# Get notified when new R version is released

Tags: r, rstudio

Simply and concisely speaking; is it possible to receive any notification when new R version is available? By notification, I mean receiving a message when running RStudio, or receiving email or whatsoever.

Comment: Aye. Join the [R-announce mailing list](https://www.r-project.org/mail.html). Next patch update is October 31, 2016.

Comment: Usually when installing new packages, we get warning that packages was *compiled* in R version x.2.0., when we have R version x.1.9.

Comment: If you are on Windows, you may also try the `installr` package which includes a function `check.for.updates.R` (besides other amenities).

Comment: @hrbrmstr Given the votes, you might want to post your comment as answer with some more explanation, so I can accept that.